# Plot 3D boolean array in Mathematica

Tags: arrays, matrix, 3d, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I have been attempting several methods to plot a 3D diagram of n by n boolean array in Mathematica but none of them produced satisfactory result. I want the 3D plot to have a cube when M[i,j,k]=1 and when M[i,j,k]=0 just leaves as blank. Below is the best result I got.

```
L=10
M = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {L, L, L}];
For[k = 1, k <= L, k++,
  For[j = 1, j <= L, j++,
   For[i = 1, i <= L, i++,
    If[M[[i, j, k]] < 0.5,
     M[[i, j, k]] = 1,
     M[[i, j, k]] = 0
     ]]]];
Image3D[M, ImageSize -> 500, Boxed -> True]
```

The Image3D function gives a very fluffy and opaque look on the cubes which I couldn't change!!

Is there someway I can change the opacity and color of the Image3D function in this case? Or is there a better way to plot this matrix?

Thanks a lot for your time!!

Comment: If you look up Image3D in the help system and click on Options and then ColorFunction you can see a little bit of information on controlling the image. Adding ColorFunction->"XRay",Background->Black gave a bit of transparency, but probably not enough. There are lots of other things you can do with ColorFunction, including Opacity, but you may have to experiment with this to get the appearance that you are looking for.

Comment: total aside, but `RandomInteger[{0,1},{L,L,L}]` will work without that messy loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to Image3D

```
 L=10;
 M=RandomInteger[{0,1},{L,L,L}];
 Graphics3D[
    First@Last@Reap[MapIndexed[ If[# == 1, Sow[Cuboid[#2]]] &, M, -1]]]
```

[image]

colorize using `Sow[{ColorData["SouthwestColors"][RandomReal[{0, 1}]], Cuboid[#2]}]`

[image]

the image3d version for comparison.

[image]

The cuboid version performs much better too. `Image3D` is so slow I don't even want to mess with it to see if there is a fix to the fuzziness.